# Trying to show fields from divs from database with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twig

In this HTML file, the Twig shows all of my fields on database. What I
 was trying to do with jQuery is to show only the first 2 fields of the
 database and with the button `show more`, show more 2 fields, but I'm a
 beginner in jQuery and I need some help. Any tip would be awesome.

```
<div id="processador" class="expandContent">
   <h3 class="header">
      <div class="headerColumn1">Processador</div>
      <div class="headerColumn2 expand"><img src="img/plus.png"/></div>
      <div class="expandedContentClearFloat"></div>
   </h3>
   <div class="expandedContent" id="123">
      {% for item in processador %}
      <div class="product-removal" id="aas">
         <article class="product">
            <header>
               <img src="{{ item.img|e }}">
            </header>
            <div class="content">
               <button name="proc" id="{{ item.id|e }}" type="button"
                  class="close close-processador pull-right" aria-label="Close"
                  data-id="{{ item.id|e }}" data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
               <h1>{{ item.marca|e }}</h1>
               {{ item.descr|e }}
            </div>
            <footer class="content">
               <h2 class="full-price fixed fixed-processador">
                  {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
               </h2>
               <a data-versao="{{item.versao|e}}" class="adicionar adicionar-processador pull-right full-price"
                  data-modelo="{{ item.modelo|e }}" data-id="{{ item.id|e }}"
                  data-preco="{{ item.preco_unit|e }}">
                  <h2 class="full-price">
                     {{ item.preco_unit|e }}€
                  </h2>
               </a>
               <h2 class="price">
                  {{ item.preco_unit|e }}
               </h2>
            </footer>
         </article>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <button id="showmore" text-center>Show More</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

> i saw this code but because im a beginner in this i couldnt
>   incorporate in my code

```
$(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 2).show();
    $("#showmore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have tried something don't you ? Please provide the code that is not working. You can achieve this mostly with CSS.

Comment: i saw this code but i can t incoporate in my code

Comment: $(function () {
    $("div").slice(0, 2).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("div:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
        if ($("div:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});

Comment: Great, please edit your question and put this snippet in a code section.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by following below steps:

1. On page load fetch first two rows from Db using limit and offset.
2. Store offset in hidden field. Ex: offset 0.
3. When user click    on show more get the value of hidden offset value, Add 2 in offset    value using send an Ajax request to the server along with offset    value.
4. On server side use limit 2 and for offset use the offset    you get from the url.Fetch two more rows from DB.
5. Return data    using json_encode and on client side decode the data using    `$.parseJSON(data)`
6. Append HTML to your div with new data. Update    the hidden value of offset with new value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use mostly CSS and a simple click event handler (see snippet below).
Use the twig [`loop.index`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) to add extra class on elements you want to hide/show.

```
<div class="product-removal{%if loop.index > 1 %} additional{%endif%}">
```

```js
$('#showmore').on('click', function(e){
    this.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
#showmore{cursor: pointer; display:inline-block;margin:10px 0;}
.additional{display: none}
.show ~ .additional{display: block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-removal" id="aas">
   <article class="product">
   LOREM IPSUM
   </article>
</div>
<div class="product-removal" id="yyy">
   <article class="product">
   LOREM IPSUM
   </article>
</div>
<span id="showmore">Show more</span>
<div class="product-removal additional" id="yyy">
   <article class="product">
   ADDITIONAL LOREM IPSUM …
   </article>
</div>
```

If there are loads of elements to hide, consider retrieving additional entries using JavaScript and AJAX. And add the `additional` class to newly added item like above.